# Trying to remove .html from mobile

Tags: jquery, html, .htaccess

I have recently used

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L
```

to remove the .html from my URLS

However I use .com/mobile for the mobile sites. Now the redirect is in place when a link is clicked on a mobile platform without the HTML the page is redirected to the desktop site. Is there a way of fixing this issue? Do I have to put the rewrite code within the mobile section of the htacess? Unsure what to do.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: I'm not an htaccess Jedi Master... But from my understanding, a rewrite rule in htaccess basically acts as a before load redirect. If you remove the .html for something else, ensure that the resulting URL exists. --- What I think you wish to achieve should be made with an `index.php` which includes the .html file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code below in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301]
```